# How to get parameter value inside a string?

Tags: javascript

Here's a thing i've been trying to resolve...

We've got some data from an ajax call and the result data is between other stuff a huge string with key:value data. For example:

"2R=OK|2M=2 row(s) found|V1=1,2|"

Is it posible for js to do something like:
var value = someFunction(str, param);

so if i search for "V1" parameter it will return "1,2"

I got this running on Sql server no sweat, but i'm struggling with js to parse the string.

So far i'm able to do this by a VERY rudimentary for loop like this:

```
var str = "2R=OK|2M=2 row(s) found|V1=1,2|";
var param = "V1";
var arr = str.split("|");
var i = 0;
var value = "";
for(i = 0; i<arr.length; ++i){
    if( arr[i].indexOf(param)>-1 ){
        value = arr[i].split("=")[1];
    }
}
console.log(value);
```

if i put that into a function it works, but i wonder if there's a more efficient way to do it, maybe some regex? but i suck at it. Hopefully somebody may shine a light on this for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you and it's delimiters are configurable (if you wish to parse a similar string with different delimiters, you can just pass in the delimiters as arguments):

```
var parseKeyValue = (function(){

  return function(str, search, keyDelim, valueDelim){
    keyDelim = quote(keyDelim || '|');
    valueDelim = quote(valueDelim || '=');

    var regexp = new RegExp('(?:^|' + keyDelim + ')' + quote(search) + valueDelim + '(.*?)(?:' + keyDelim + '|$)');
    var result = regexp.exec(str);

    if(result && result.length > 1)
      return result[1];
  };

  function quote(str){
    return (str+'').replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
  }
})();
```

[Quote function borrowed form this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2593661/772035) 
Usage examples:

```
var str = "2R=OK|2M=2 row(s) found|V1=1,2|";
var param = "V1";
parseKeyValue(str, param); // "1,2"

var str = "2R=OK&2M=2 row(s) found&V1=1,2";
var param = "2R";
parseKeyValue(str, param, '&'); // "OK"

var str = 
"2R=>OK\n\
2M->2 row(s) found\n\
V1->1,2";

var param = "2M";
parseKeyValue(str, param, '\n', '->'); // "2 row(s) found"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help mate, @David beat you to it but your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Ok, sorry for the delay, but THIS is the correct way to do it, no matter how many parameters are inside the string, this function will get you the desired parameter value and nothing else. Hat tip to you sir @Paulpro you pointed me into some interesting stuff right there.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for your specific use-case:

```
function getValueByKey(haystack, needle) {
    if (!haystack || !needle) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var re = new RegExp(needle + '=(.+)');
        return haystack.match(re)[1];
    }
}

var str = "2R=OK|2M=2 row(s) found|V1=1,2|",
    test = getValueByKey(str, 'V1');
console.log(test);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Q3SzV/2/).

And, to include the separator in your search (in order to prevent `somethingElseV1` matching for `V1`):

```
function getValueByKey(haystack, needle, separator) {
    if (!haystack || !needle) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var re = new RegExp('\\' + separator + needle + '=(.+)\\' + separator);
        return haystack.match(re)[1];
    }
}

var str = "2R=OK|2M=2 row(s) found|V1=1,2|",
    test = getValueByKey(str, 'V1', '|');
console.log(test);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Q3SzV/3/).

Note that this approach does require the use of the `new RegExp()` constructor (rather than creating a regex-literal using `/.../`) in order to pass variables into the regular expression.

Similarly, because we're using a string to create the regular expression within the constructor, we need to double-escape characters that require escaping (escaping first within the string and then escaping within in the created RegExp).

References:

- [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Comment: Nice! thanks, but there's a small detail, if the searchString is something like this "2R=OK|2M=2 row(s) found|V1=1,2|V2=Test|" and i use your method looking for V1 value, i get "1,2|V2=Test|" is there a way to tell the regex to stop looking after a pipe "|" is found?

Comment: oh Snap! you beat me to it, the second one is the one! thanks a lot buddy i owe you a cold one. I need to get better at regex since it's been saving me a lot of time and coding since i can remember but i'm no good at it. Thanks for the references!

Comment: David thanks for your help, this function is as far as i can tell very powerful but lacks some important detail, that is, returning only the value of a given parameter, indeed it looks for the parameter and gets its value but also returns the rest of the string from the parameter found. The links you posted were a great help, much appreciated, but @Paul's method is the one that i will implement on my utilities file with some tweaks once i get to master all this regex sweetness. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WPUzR/) is another approach:

HTML:

```
<div id="2R"></div>
<div id="2M"></div>
<div id="V1"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function createDictionary(input) {
    var splittedInput = input.split(/[=|]/),
        kvpCount = Math.floor(splittedInput.length / 2),
        i, key, value,
        dictionary = {};

    for (i = 0; i < kvpCount; i += 1) {
        key = splittedInput[i * 2];
        value = splittedInput[i * 2 + 1];
        dictionary[key] = value;
    }
    return dictionary;
}

var input = "2R=OK|2M=2 row(s) found|V1=1,2|",
    dictionary = createDictionary(input),
    div2R = document.getElementById("2R"),
    div2M = document.getElementById("2M"),
    divV1 = document.getElementById("V1");

div2R.innerHTML = dictionary["2R"];
div2M.innerHTML = dictionary["2M"];
divV1.innerHTML = dictionary["V1"];
```

Result:

```
OK
2 row(s) found
1,2
```

Comment: Interesting approach but i think it's a little slow when dealing with long strings, in my case i can receive up to 80 parameters on a string (not a fan but a requirement) and the loop you do is basically the same as my initial approach. Thanks mate for some cool tips and that dictionary you did there is quite handy, maybe i'll take some of that concept for my own